# Magento 2: Dashboard Chart, Want custom Amount range on y axis?

Tags: magento2, custom, chart

I want to add custom Amount range on y-axis like 0,5000,10000,15000,20000 so on ...
how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please debug with this file to find below content to check how its working.

```
vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php

elseif ($idx == 'y') {
                $valueBuffer[] = $indexid . ":|" . implode('|', $yLabels);
            }
```